# How is this voltage cutoff circuit working?

Tags: circuit-analysis

I am working on a project. I needed a voltage cutoff circuit. I found many online and I chose one of them. 
[image: voltage cutoff curcuit]

Now I want to understand the circuit. Why is it working as it is? I dont know how to analysis it. My first thought was to approach it piece by piece, but I still dont know what is the best way to do that. 
Please tell me the best way to develop sense of interpretation for such circuits which includes opamps and mosfets and etc.

Okay. Now i start decompose it. First part is about comparator. Here is schematics for it[image: comparator part explanation]

Comment: You should include the part number for the comparator (not an op-amp) in the circuit, link to its datasheet and have a quick look at a comparator tutorial online and then refine your question. What is your best guess at how it works?

Comment: The curtain will rise in your mind one morning. Nobody can tell you how to lift it other than keep looking at circuits and keep thinking.

Comment: @Enes: You've added some info. Now what is the state of the output with IN+ is higher than IN-. Then at what Vv will the comparator change state?

Comment: @Transistor I apologize. Kudos for your teaching aim.